# Giving Users Full Control of their local drives?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

Is there a way to give a domain user full control of their local drives at the Group Policy end?

Specifically, my IT Manager wants the following:

a) Desktop control allowed
b) Full access to local hard drives
c) Software Installation NOT Allowed
d) Existing software Updates Allowed
e) Install additional printers

Allowed At the moment, our Win2003 setup does not allow users to do a,b,d,e - I wondered if there was a way using GP to enable these?

Comment: If you provide additional details of what you want to accomplish, you may get answers that don't involve opening everything up to end users.

Comment: Specifically, my IT Manager wants the following:

a) Desktop control allowed
b) Full access to local hard drives
c) Software Installation NOT Allowed
d) Existing software Updates Allowed
e) Install additional printers Allowed

At the moment, our Win2003 setup does not allow users to do a,b,d,e - I wondered if there was a way using GP to enable these?

Comment: You should add your comment to your question above for clarity.  

A,C,D,E can be accomplished without making Domain Users members of local Administrators.  For what purpose does your manager think "Full" access to the local hard drives is required? Does this mean users can delete the contents of %WINDIR%?  If the users only need to be able to browse local disks, this is not an issue.

Comment: We're migrating from a setup where all users (<100) where logged in as Administrators on their XP machines, so I think the idea is to ease their transition by not restricting where they can save their files. Many of them would have data files off the root of C: etc.

I'd like to make their machines as secure/safe as possible, but we also don't want to "demonise" the new network setup by lots of restrictions. 

All advice is gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it's a registry based change so you have to configure an .ADM file. Full details at Microsoft [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289). (You obviously want the 'Do not restrict drives' option)

Answer (score 1):

I would observe that what you're trying to do is a really bad idea.

Having said that, you can use the [File System security policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782533(WS.10).aspx) to grant access to files / folders using Group Policy.

You have conflicting requirements (and wholly orthagonal requirements to your question, too). If you're taking away "Administator" rights but giving users "Full Control" of the disk the OS is installed onto then you're just giving them an ability to get "Administrator" rights back (as well as installing software, malicious software, etc) by modifying OS files.

If you're trying to get users to stop being "Administrators" and start cleaning up your support procedures your best bet is to look at using "Folder Redirection" and mounting a political campaign of convincing users that their data will be safer, more secure, and more accessible by storing it in their "My Documents" folder (which you'll then redirect to a server computer).

There's no good reason to be saving files on a local hard disk drive. Any reason you can think of isn't good enough. Microsoft has done a great job, in the last few server / client OS releases, of providing mechanisms to store data server-side, have it available client-side even when disconneced from the network, and all the while keeping the data safe and secure.

It takes hard work, time, and effort to transition away from a culture of "everyone's an Administrator". You'll have to use tools like "Process Monitor" to beat your software into submission re: running as non-privileged users. If you can get it done, though, you will be a much better world re: recurring support cost, fighting "fires", etc.

Answer (score 0):

by default only domain admins group is added as local admins on a pc. But you can on the computer go to the "computer management" (right click on computer and click manage) and in groups - administrators go and add domain users aswell. Thats the way i do it. its a long process if you need to do it on alot of computers.

So if anyone got a better solution i wouldnt mind either.

Comment: The better solution is to use Group Policy Restricted Groups to populate the local groups automagically: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320045

However adding "Domain Users" to the local Administrators group is, um, brave/stupid (your choice).

Comment: @Morten: He was looking for a way to do this via GPO.

Comment: I agree that it probably isnt a good idea.  If they arent already running as local admins I would keep it that way.  We tried it and had major issues with clever malware that depends on the users lack of knowledge to get permission to run.

Comment: I've looked into the use of Restricted Groups, and I'm a bit flummoxed to be honest.   

How do I include the local Administrators group (all I can see are the domain accounts).   

Do I just enter 'Administrators' after I right click and select Add Group? Then I add the security group that contains our users to the 'Members of the group' list?

Comment: @Ian. Select 'Add Group' and enter the _exact_ local group name (don't click 'browse') you wish to populate and click 'OK'.  Also, please consider other options besides adding 'Domain Users' to the local Administrators group, please.

Comment: @jscott, thanks for your help and advice. We've previously run with all users as local Administrators, so it wouldn't be a step back for us, just not a step forward in terms of security. However, as it stands, we're having a lot of difficulty with basic file operations that they expect to work, because of the more restrictive default file permissions/access rights. Updating software is also an issue. 

I'm open to other suggestions/options instead of adding Domain Users into local Admin, I just don't know any other options.